# Busines Object 4.1 geo-distributed server configuration

Tags: tomcat, business-objects

I have regionally distributed users with a data centre in each region.  I would like to set up local Tomcat / BO Servers / database in each region, with a central CMS and monitoring host.

I have read the Admin guide for server groups.  That's quite clear about which servers will process a scheduled report.  I understand how I can alter connection at run-time so a report instance brings its data from the correct regional database

My question concerns the other two parts of my installation.  How can I ensure a regional Tomcat only sends requests to servers in the same data centre?  How can I associate an IFR with just one region so the report definition is co-located with the people who will use it and the servers which will render it?

BO 4.1 on Windows Server 2008R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: you cannot. Moreover, you can only have **one set of active input and output FRS servers**. There may be different ones running in your environment, but only one will be active while the other ones are passive, waiting to take over when the active one fails or stops.

Regarding **Tomcat** (or any other application server): you have no control over what BO server they will be talking to. The web application (BOE) hosted on Tomcat will send its request to the CMS, which will then provide it with the address of the server(s) to use in order to fulfil the request.

As for **servers groups**: there is no way to link users groups (e.g. all users for country x) to a server group. You can only assign a document (e.g. web intelligence document) to a server group. Also, this only works for existing documents (and you have to assign it one document at a time or use the SDK) and thus not for newly created documents. This is quite a shortcoming esp. for geographically distributed environments.

I would recommend against using a **central CMS** and having the other BI4 servers decentralised, for the simple reason that there's quite a lot of network traffic flowing between the CMS and the other servers. The latency introduced by this will directly affect your end-user.

An alternative setup you could try for such a deployment is to define separate platforms for each geographic location (i.e. decentralised CMS servers), linking them together using **replication**. That way, you're sure that the requests from users in country x will not be travelling halfway around the world for a refresh of their report. Keep in mind though that replication in BusinessObjects is not a widely used feature.

Comment: Thanks @Kristof.  This confirms a lot of what we're seeing through profiling the running application.  Can you point me towards any official SAP documentaion which covers this?  We've quite a lot riding on the outcome of this and exec's will be asking.

Comment: @MichaelGreen All this is covered in the [Business Intelligence Platform Administrator Guide](http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sbo41/en/sbo41sp3_bip_admin_en.pdf), however you won't find the statements I made in there, at least not explicitly. Have a look at **federation** (chapter 23) which deals with the cross-site replication topic. Chapter 3 discusses the **architecture**, and chapter 10 section 7 contains information on **server groups**.

Comment: For completeness - it was the comments in the Administratior Guide on server groups which made us believe this configuration would be feasible.  It is not.  Without being able to localise Tomcat handling or OFR writes our WAN load will be unbearable.  I have observed the behaviour @Kristof describes in our test environment.  Federation of independent installations will allow localisation of load but does not permit a shared license pool, AFAIK.

Comment: Business Intelligence Platform Planning Guide (xi4_planning_en.pdf), Section 3.2.10.1 Designing a multiple-server system for high availability, page 84: "Your deployment can have multiple Input and Output FRSes. The first File Repository Server pair to register with the CMS cluster becomes the active FRS pair and the other FRS services are considered passive. Although all File Repository Server services run simultaneously, only the active
FRS pair handles requests."